# Force memory allocation in Java

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, arrays

I am aware that memory allocation is not explicitly required in [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), as the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) handles allocation behind the scenes. Even though I am not required to allocate memory, for the sake of testing a memory greedy application, how would I be able to hold objects of certain numbers of bytes?

The current solution is to instantiate arrays of the primitive 'byte'. If I want to hold 5 MB worth of objects, I create an array of bytes.

```
byte[] b = new byte[5000000];
```

Is there a better way to explicitly allocate memory in a Java JVM, if only for the sake creating / releasing objects of known size for some unit tests?

Comment: I don't understand the question... new is not good?

Comment: Is it for JNI stuff? If so, allocating a DirectByteBuffer will definitely allocate your memory then & there.

Comment: @Ed H., This is not for JNI. Missed the 'new', edited post.

Comment: What would make something a "better way"?  Or, what's bad about what you're doing now?  Offhand, I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Creating an object seemed hackish, I was hoping for more direct control.  True, in C I would have no problem with this, but the app is in java and this is a corner case I need to write some blocks for, not a huge architectural change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a better way of doing it. 'new' is the only way to explicitly occupy memory (except allocating stack by calling a method, for example).

```
byte b = new byte[MEM_SIZE];
```

is the most controllable way of doing it. It won't allocate exactly 5000000 bytes, thanks to object overhead, but it's pretty close.